# Find String Name Using REGEX into Ansible

Tags: regex

Need to find string name for below output file using regexp.
I have used this command regexp_search(([A-Z])_ID) but only get Description_ID(key).
I need to find the value which is installed into this key. **Eg: Server**

```
"",
            "SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Feb 16 11:41:31 2021",
            "",
            "Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.",
            "",
            "IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORISED TO ACCESS THIS COMPUTER SYSTEM THEN YOU SHOULD DISCONNECT NOW.",
            "",
            "",
            "IF YOU ARE NOT AUTHORISED TO ACCESS THIS COMPUTER SYSTEM THEN YOU SHOULD DISCONNECT NOW.",
            "",
            "",
            "Last Successful login time: Tue Feb 16 2021 11:40:51 +11:00",
            "",
            "Connected to:",
            "Oracle Database 16c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production",
            "With the Partitioning option",
            "",
            "",
            **"Description_ID",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Server",**
            "",
            "SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 16c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production",
            "With the Partitioning option"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a second capture group, matching the line below it having hyphens between the double quotes.

```
"(\w+)_ID".*\r?\n\s*"-+",\r?\n\s*"([^"]+)"
```

The pattern matches:

- `"(\w+)_ID".*` Capture 1 or more word chars in **group 1**, match `_ID` and the rest of the line
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `"-+",` Match consecutive hyphens between double quotes and the comma at the end
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `"([^"]+)"` Capture what is between the double quotes in **group 2**

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ss8ya/1)

Another option could be matching all non word characters after the Description until a line that has word characters between the double quotes

```
"(\w+)_ID"\W*\r?\n\s*"(\w+)"
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYkRXy/1)

Comment: @ParthShah What did not work? How did you use the pattern?

Comment: ** is not available into the actual output.            **"Description_ID",
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
            "Server",**

Comment: The second thing stdout_lines is not working with regex_search option. So I need to use stdout only instead of stdout_lines.

Comment: @ParthShah I am not sure what you mean by that, but if the newlines are a problem you might also use `"(\w+)_ID"\W*"(\w+)"` https://regex101.com/r/NxzKEK/1

Comment: @ParthShah Try it without the quotes `(\w+)_ID\W*(\w+)`  https://regex101.com/r/tMeIqt/1 or `(\w+)_ID.*\r?\n\s*-+\r?\n(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/Co6CYz/1

Comment: Or matching the literal backslashes https://regex101.com/r/wwhdNI/1

Comment: @ParthShah Any feedback?

Comment: "(\w+)_ID"\W*"(\w+)"  this one is working fine. Thank you. Much appreciated.